# Setting Maven Java compiler debug to false does not remove line number table?

Tags: java, maven-2, compiler-construction

Perhaps this is my lack of understanding, but I would have assumed that doing this in a Maven Java project would disable all debug info from going into the Class file:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However, I just tested it  and while the local variable table is gone, and the source file reference is gone, the line number table is still present.  I did a `javap -l MyClass` and still got things like:

```
protected com.mycorp.myapp.randomMethod();
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 197: 0
   line 68: 4
   line 69: 9
   line 70: 14
   line 198: 19
```

Clearly, the stuff is still in there....I think.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This looks like [MCOMPILER-114](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-114). Using the following seems to work with the version 2.3.2 of the plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <debug>true</debug>
      <debuglevel>none</debuglevel>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

(yeah, I know, that's not what the documentation is saying, but well, it works)

Comment: Wow.  I am stunned.  I wonder how many people out there never bothered to disassemble their java classes and discover this.

Comment: I just tried your settings, and while the resulting class file is smaller, the line table is still there!!!

Comment: @HDave Did you `clean`?? I tested this before posting and the line table is clearly absent using the above settings.

Comment: I did run clean.  After 2 hours of trying to figure out why my effective-pom has debuglevel=none the the call to javac only had a plain "-g" option I tried a newer version of the compiler plugin.  I was using 2.0.2 which is the default for Maven, when I switched to 2.3.2 I replicated your behavior exactly.